# Virtual template member in a base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following class that I want to serve as an "interface" for other classes. I am using Eigen library.

```
class MultivariateDistribution
{
public:
    MultivariateDistribution() = default;
    template <typename T>
    MultivariateDistribution(const Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic> &dataset) { maximumLikelihoodParameterEstimation(dataset); }
    virtual ~MultivariateDistribution() = default;

    template <typename T>
    virtual void maximumLikelihoodParameterEstimation(const Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic> &dataset) = 0;
};
```

I have dervied a class from this one and implemented all the required methods but the compiler yields the following error:

```
 error C2898: 'void MultivariateDistribution::maximumLikelihoodParameterEstimation(const Eigen::Matrix<T,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> &)': member function templates
cannot be virtual
```

It is not possible to declare a member function with templated parameters? If so, how can I implement a similar behaviour to receive any type of Eigen Matrix?

Thank you.

Comment: No you can't have templated virtual function, how would the vtable look like if you could?

Comment: So in order to implement a similar behaviour, I have to overload the function with all types of Eigen Matrix? I see that Christophe marked as duplicated, If he can post the link of the thread I would appreciatte to see the answers.

Comment: That depends. Do you really need dynamic dispatch?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know what exactly means dynamic dispatch. I want to allow the users to pass a Matrix of ints, doubles, floats, uchar, etc without forcing them to do a conversion

Comment: 1. The error message gives a quite precise answer to your question: `member function templates cannot be virtual`. 2. Why do you want to use virtual functions here? They only apply where you want run time polymorphism (i.e. in your case you have multiple different types derived from `MultivariateDistribution` where the selection of one of them is due to user input).

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding something... I am not a hard c++ programmer. What I want is to allow the user to pass an Eigen matrix of any type (int, double, float, and so on). I templated the function because I thought it was the easiest and shortest way to do it. I also can overload the function of all types, I don't know if this is the "correct way" to to it.

Comment: That is the correct way to do this, what I don't understand is why you think it needs to be virtual as well? `MultivariateDistribution` is not something I expect to be a base class of some hierarchy, surely there's only one way to do `maximumLikelihoodParameterEstimation` for a `MultivariateDistribution`.

Comment: Because I want to derive for example a `MultivariateNormal`, a `MultivariateTStudent` and so on. The maximum likelihood implementation for the estimation of the parameters of a specific distribution will be different for each one. An in order to allow to other users to implement their own distributions, I want to provide an "interface" to indicate the user which methods are required to work in the framework.

Comment: Okay, but surely the implementation is not something your framework won't be aware off until run-time. What you are looking for may be static polymorphism accomplished by the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: Be aware that all your code will need to be rather template heavy.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will read it, and if I see that the code is going to become to a hell, I will drop the idea and force the user to pass a Matrix of a specific type.
Thank you. How can I vote you?

Comment: You can't, since I didn't provide an answer. But don't worry about it, I just hope I was able to help.